# Angular ngFor in ngFor formControlName : Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular, nested, ngfor

Starting out with Angular and trying to iterate over an array of objects that contain a nested array of objects. StackBlitz link below has all the code and text.

For app.component.html line 6-8 accessing the  on line 17 fails.

Error:

```
Cannot find control with path: 'array -> 0 -> notePartials -> 0'
Cannot find control with path: 'array -> 0 -> notePartials -> 0 -> id'
```

If you expand the FormGroup printed in the console the data is at value -> array -> 0 -> notePartials -> 0

At a loss for what may be the issue... Displays without issue in a , but when trying to access from an input it fails.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ydh1rz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a9baei?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for possible solution.
I have added all the formcontrols for notePartials object in the form so that you can access them in the html.

Comment: So the data was all there and fine, but the nested array needed to be mapped for the form controls to be able to find it is what I'm getting. Thanks!